# Keras back propagation

Tags: neural-network, keras, backpropagation

Suppose I have defined a network using Keras as follows:

```python
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_shape=(10,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='sigmoid'))
```

It has some weights:

```python
[array([[ 0.33494413, -0.34308964,  0.12796348,  0.17187083, -0.40254939,
    -0.06909397, -0.30374748,  0.14217842,  0.41163749, -0.15252003],
   [-0.07053435,  0.53712451, -0.43015254, -0.28653857,  0.53299475, ...
```

When I give it some input:

```python
[[ 0.   0.5  0.   0.5  1.   1.   0.   0.5  0.5  0.5]]
```

It produces some output:

```python
[0.5476531982421875, 0.5172237753868103, 0.5247090458869934, 0.49434927105903625, 0.4599153697490692, 0.44612908363342285, 0.4727349579334259, 0.5116984844207764, 0.49565717577934265]
```

Whereas the desired output is:

```python
[0.6776225034927386, 0.0, 0.5247090458869934, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.4727349579334259, 0.5116984844207764, 0.49565717577934265]
```

Making the Error Value:

```python
[0.12996930525055106, -0.5172237753868103, 0.0, -0.49434927105903625, -0.4599153697490692, -0.44612908363342285, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I can then calculate the evaluated gradients as follows:

```python
outputTensor = model.output
listOfVariableTensors = model.trainable_weights
gradients = k.gradients(outputTensor, listOfVariableTensors)
trainingInputs = inputs
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
evaluated_gradients = sess.run(gradients, feed_dict={model.input: trainingInputs})
```

Which yeilds the evaluated gradients:

```python
[array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
     0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
   [ 0.01015381,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.03375177, -0.05576257,
     0.03318337, -0.02608909, -0.06644543, -0.03461133,  0.        ],
   [ 0.02030762,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.06750354, -0.11152515,
     0.06636675, -0.05217818, -0.13289087, -0.06922265,  0.        ],...
```

I would like to use these gradients to adjust my model, but I am losing track of the math & theory of backpropagation. Am I on the right track?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the end? Because Keras has all the training loop already implemented.

Comment: It's just an "academic" exercise for myself. I wanted to see if I could tweak a network to produce an expected output. I can calculate gradients for a single sigmoid layer, but I get lost on many layers of different nonlinear types.

Comment: You can use the gradients to "tweak" the network but for that you use gradient descent, not back-propagation. Back-propagation is just a way to compute gradients efficiently using the chain rule.

Comment: Thank you Matias, that much I understand. The only problem is that when I stake successive steps in the direction of this gradient (recalculating in between), I don't see it moving towards the desired output so much. So I think I am calculating (asking tf to calculate) the gradient incorrectly.